Java Spring Boot, bucle infinito en la respuesta
Tengo estas entidades
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product extends BaseEntity {
  @Column
  String name;

  @Column
  BigDecimal price;

  @Column
  Integer stock;

  @Column
  String description;

  @OneToMany(targetEntity = Transaction.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "productId")
  List<Transaction> transactions;

  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Brand.class)
  @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id")
  Brand brand;
}

@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Entity

@Table(name = "brands")
public class Brand extends BaseEntity {
  @Column
  String name;

  @OneToMany(targetEntity = Product.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "brand")

  List<Product> products;
}

pero no entiendo porque la respuesta me genera un bucle infinito, entiendo que es porque el padre tiene una referencia del hijo, y el hijo del padre y asi sucesivamanente.
He visto soluciones con el @JsonIgnore, a lo que pregunto, si utilizo esa anotacion, y en alguna solicitud necesito que me llegue esa informacion del padre, o parte de ella, voy a poder hacerlo?
Muchas gracias
